# What bootstrap container would I use to the centre the text?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What bootstrap container would I use in order for me to centre the text below?

I'm trying to get the text to be centred and I think this has something to do with me picking the wrong container?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h9eg768y/)

```
 <!-- Intro Section -->
  <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-justified">
          <p class="main1">Welcome to my digital portfolio</p>
          <p>My name is Liam Docherty</p>
          <p>I'm a web developer from London.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Centered like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/h9eg768y/1/

Comment: @Korgrue Perfect! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate class in Bootstrap 4:

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h2>Titel</h2> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: text-center is available in Bootstrap 3 as well

Comment: change text-justified with text-center -> thats is

Comment: Thanks for the help!